# Autocomplete ,How to manually generate search event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i am using jquery autocomplete plugin.i defined autocomplete on a text input element.i defined many methods also on autocomplete.i can't share whole code.but giving brief idea about my scenario.here is small code snippet

```
j$(".quick-text-search").autocomplete({
source: function(request,response){},
search: function(){console.log('coming to search');},
});
```

i defined source and search method.when i type in .quick-text-search element everything is working fine and its showing list items also. but when any other element is generating search event then no list is showing.for example from element checkbox when checkbox value is changed .here is code snippet of that

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){

                  // j$(this).parent().addClass('active');
                   var catList = getSelectedValues('category-selected');
                console.log("catlist");
                console.log(catList);
                 j$(".quick-text-search").autocomplete("search", "");   
                });
```

i think it should call search method .so there should something in browser console.but there is no 'coming to search' in browser console. can anyone guideline why and how to generate search event in jquery for autocomplete??

Comment: Why are you using an empty string as what to search for? Setting it to  a character works fine.

Comment: because i want to give functionality in my search method as what to search.what is in other elements i want to search on that basis.can u elaborate what will happen when i called this .autocomplete("search") method ??

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

No search will happen if the text length is less than the min options

If you go to the jQuery UI sample page: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/default.html

and you run the following into the console, nothing happens since the min length is 1.

```
$("#tags")
    .autocomplete("search", "");
```

If you change it to search for "a", it will show the results

```
$("#tags")
    .autocomplete("search", "a");
```

Now if we change the min length to zero and run the same code again the options open up

```
$("#tags")
    .autocomplete("option","minLength", 0)
    .autocomplete("search", "");
```